# Windows Server 2019 Active Directory Administrative Center does not create user home directories

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019

I started using the new Active Directory Administrative Center to setup a new Windows 2019 Server. However, I have struggled with getting users created through ADAC to get their home folders created. I believed this to be an issue of permissions, but found out that everything works perfectly well when a user gets assigned a home folder via the "old" Active Directory Computers and Users instead.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a known issue?

I basically did the same thing in both places: set the users home folder to connect to a drive (e.g. H:) and specify the UNC path as \server\homes$%username%. ADCU creates the folder right away, ADAC does not do that at all and the folder is also not created if the user logs on later.

Answer (score 0):

This is specifically a function of Active Directory Users & Computers (dsa.msc), then again, only if the account performing the action has sufficient rights on the file system.

Also, it would not (and likely should not) get created automatically upon user logon and the users should not have the appropriate permissions to create folders in that path.